# how to create comparator with generic Treeset?

Tags: java, generics, treeset

in need help with generics ,i have this class:

```
public class Course<T> {

    private T idOrName;
    private float avg;

    public Course(T idOrName,float avg){
        this.idOrName=idOrName;
        this.avg=avg;

    }


}
```

....and i need to make the user choose between String or Integer and then create a Treeset and sort it by this generics type.how can i do that if i dont know if its a number or String?? i have a problem with making the comparator :

```
    Set<Course<?>> list=new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Course<?>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Course<?> o1, Course<?> o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the zero-argument `TreeSet` constructor?

Comment: yes but i need to compare between the 'course' which contains string or integer

Comment: Will the set contain entries of mixed types? I.e. some are String and some are Integer courses?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to indicate that the expected class must be `Comparable` by proceeding as next

```
public class Course<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   ...
}
```

Then your generic comparator could be something like this:

```
Set<Course<?>> list = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Course<?>>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(Course<?> o1, Course<?> o2) {
        // If idOrName are both of the same class then we use the
        // comparator of this class as we know that they are Comparable
        if (o1.idOrName.getClass() == o2.idOrName.getClass()) {
            return ((Comparable)o1.idOrName).compareTo((Comparable)o2.idOrName);
        }
        // If they are not of the same class we compare the name of the class
        return o1.idOrName.getClass().getName().compareTo(
            o2.idOrName.getClass().getName()
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: ok..ill try this..but whats the different between extends to implements..when do i need to try both?

Answer (score 1):

Go for duplication of the fields. Any other solution would be more circumstantial. Here I added a `toString` that unifies both cases.

```
public class Course {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float avg;

    public Course(int id, float avg){
        this(id, "", avg);
    }

    public Course(String name, float avg){
        this(0, name, avg);
    }

    private Course(int id, String name, float avg){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.avg = avg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id != 0 ? String.value(id) : name;
    }
}
```

And a comparator (since java 8):

```
Comparator.comparingInt(course -> course.id)
          .thenComparing(course -> course.name);

Comparator.comparingInt(Course::getId)
          .thenComparing(Course::getName);
```